# How can I smooth and repair cracks in a plaster wall?

Tags: repair, walls

[image]

My walls are uneven and have these covered cracks all over them, can I sand it down and slim coat it to make a smooth wall?

Comment: pretty hard to sand down if it is concrete

Comment: If it is concrete a cement grinder would easily eat through that. If not, then yes, you can do what you are thinking. Start by using a wide taping knife, 5-in-1 tool, etc., to knock down the high spots.

Answer (score 2):

This is the step by step process I use.

- Dig out all the loose material from each crack. Blow out debris with compressed air.
- Brush a bonding agent into the cracks and allow it to dry.
- Force setting type joint compound into cracks and while still wet over lay the cracks with fiberglass mesh tape and press it flat into mud against surface.
- Let it dry, then knock off any lumps or bumps and apply a second coat, feathering all edges.
- Let dry and sand area to smooth it out.
- Apply a coat of topping mud to perfect your patched area making it as smooth and trowel mark free as possible.
- Let dry then lightly sand remove dust and prime patched area.
- After it dries repaint the walls and ceilings with a quality acrylic paint.

Comment: Is there a reason you recommend mesh instead of paper tape? I've used both around the house and find paper far easier to finish and thinner in the amount of mud required to achieve a smooth feathered surface.

Comment: @Steven  mesh is compatible with setting mud. Paper and mesh work with standard joint compound